# Laravel filament, issue uploading file

Tags: laravel-filament

I have a small mistake with a question about how to make an action to use a modal that allows me to import an Excel or CSV file in a certain model.

For this I am using on the resource listing page,

### ListCommandCenter

```php
  <?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources\CommandCenterResource\Pages;

use App\Filament\Resources\CommandCenterResource;
use Filament\Forms\Components\FileUpload;
use Filament\Pages\Actions;
use Filament\Resources\Pages\ListRecords;

class ListCommandCenters extends ListRecords
{
     protected static string $resource = CommandCenterResource::class;

     protected function getActions(): array
     {
         return [
             Actions\CreateAction::make(),
             Actions\Action::make('importExcel')
                 ->action('openImportExcel')
                 ->form([
                     FileUpload::make('upload')
                         ->disk('local')
                         ->directory('uploads')
                         ->preserveFilenames()
                         ->acceptedFileTypes(['text/csv'])
                 ])
         ];
     }

     public function openImportExcel()
     {
         // Some logic for debugging
     }
```

When I click the button, the modal to upload the file appears, but I always get a 422.

[image]

I can't find a solution

Comment: @ManojKiranA Due to workload issues, I abandoned the attempt and did it manually

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure `APP_URL` is set corretly in .env file.

Comment: I don't put my `.env` value and if i'm in develop or production. But if you see developer tools, I'm in develop mode (localhost) and if you analize image, error is 422 not 404.

Comment: When a server returns a 422 error code, it also provides a response body that explains the error in more detail, including a list of specific validation errors or other details about why the request could not be processed. Please see that explaination part.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this by changing `variables_order` in `php.ini`

```
- variables_order="EGPCS"   // <- from this
+ variables_order="GPCS"    // <- to this
```

More info https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order